# How to save enum-type data to file?

Tags: c++, qt, enums

I have enum-type data like:

```
typedef enum
{
    NULLTYPE = 0U,
    ParameterGetType = 1U,
    ParameterSetType = 2U,
    ParameterStatusType  = 3U,
    EventActionType  = 4U,
    CommandType  = 5U,
    CommandGetType  = 6U,
    CommandSetType  = 7U,
    EquipmentIDGetType   = 15U,
    EquipmentIDSetType   = 16U,
    EquipmentIDStatusType = 17U,
    EventReportGetType  = 18U,
    EventReportSetType  = 19U,
    EventReportStatusType = 20U,
    PeriodicReportType = 21U,
    PeriodicReportGetType  = 22U,
    PeriodicReportSetType  = 23U,
    PeriodicReportStatusType  = 24U,
    CommandResponseType  = 25U,
    CommandResponseGetType  = 26U,
    CommandResponseSetType  = 27U,
    CommandResponseStatusType  = 28U,
    CommandResponseDeletedType  = 29U

}MessageType;
```

I want to save it into binary file using QByteArray and QFile::write(QByteArray),
but I don't know the length of the data, and the 'distribution' of bytes' value of the data，
(if the data is 1, will other bytes' value be zero?)
I think it is not limited to qt, how to write the data into file?

(For short-type data (MsgItem->PIN), I will do this:)

```
QByteArray bytes;
bytes.append(((MsgItem->PIN)>>8) & 0xff);
bytes.append((MsgItem->PIN) & 0xff);
MsgFile->write(bytes);
MsgFile->flush();
```

Comment: If you change over to c++11 enum classes you will know the size of the enum data, because you can choose!

Comment: c is required for the internal data. :)

Comment: Can you give a limit, because I want to save it as a fixed unit.

Comment: sizeof(MessageType) == 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the enum value to a fixed-size integer (use `<cstdint>` and e.g. `uint16_t`) and do whatever byte-ordering manipulations you need.